# Angular2 Installing 3rd party plugin with Angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My Angular-cli's angular 2 version is 2.0.0-rc.1. I am trying to install [angular2-grid](https://github.com/BTMorton/angular2-grid) and followed the exact way it described in the tutorial, but it shwos me this error.

```
    zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/angular2-grid/dist/NgGrid 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM6591:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/node_modules/angular2-grid/dist/NgGrid
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/node_modules/angular2-grid/dist/NgGrid as "angular2-grid" from http://localhost:4200/app/banbeis.component.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/node_modules/angular2-grid/dist/NgGrid(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/node_modules/angular2-grid/dist/NgGrid(…)
```

I ran thier Demo example ,it worked but after then I tried with angular-cli but no hard luck yet. A working code will be appreciable :)

Comment: Did you add angular2-grid to the vendorNpmFiles array in angular-cli-build.js?
More code would be useful to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: yes I did , but the issue was still there. Posting my solution down below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with the help of BTMorton(author of angular2-grid), I opened an issue in the angular2-grid [github](https://github.com/BTMorton/angular2-grid/issues/93) . I am posting my solution here.

In my angular-cli-build.js , I have to make it this way

```
...
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      ...
      'angular2-grid/dist/**/*.js'
      ...
```

In system-configs.ts

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
    'angular2-grid': 'vendor/angular2-grid/dist'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
    'angular2-grid': { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

The cli does some weird bundling, hence the many error.